Unity 2d A* Pathfinding cant get negative x velocity
im making a script about a topdown 2d car Ai Movement to move around the city randomly via waypoint using A* and the part of that script is to change thing like the waypoint scan range(collider offset) and the animtion to match the the car direction, then right,up,down direction work fine but left didnt work
void UpdateDirectionAndAnimation(Vector3 desiredVelocity)
{
bool isHorizontal = Mathf.Abs(desiredVelocity.x) > Mathf.Abs(desiredVelocity.y);
if (isHorizontal)
{
    if (desiredVelocity.x > 0)
    {
        UpdateCarState(currentSpriteSet.rightSprite, currentAnimationSet.rightClip.name, leftRightCarColliderConfig, new Vector3(1, 1, 1), viewRangeConfig.rightOffset);
    }
    else if (desiredVelocity.x < 0)
    {
        UpdateCarState(currentSpriteSet.leftSprite, currentAnimationSet.leftClip.name, leftRightCarColliderConfig, new Vector3(-1, 1, 1), viewRangeConfig.leftOffset);
    }
}
else
{
    if (desiredVelocity.y > 0)
    {
        UpdateCarState(currentSpriteSet.upSprite, currentAnimationSet.upClip.name, upDownCarColliderConfig, new Vector3(1, 1, 1), viewRangeConfig.upOffset);
    }
    else if (desiredVelocity.y < 0)
    {
        UpdateCarState(currentSpriteSet.downSprite, currentAnimationSet.downClip.name, upDownCarColliderConfig, new Vector3(1, 1, 1), viewRangeConfig.downOffset);
    }
}

}
it supposed to change the waypoint scan range collider and the animtion to the left but stay on the right when the move left

i dont want the car to do a "Moonwalk" movement so i force it to scan the area ahead of it with a child object as waypoint scan range

nah dont mind about this one i found the problem its becz the local scale
